# error "has no segue with identifier" adding split ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboard

I'm adding a split ViewController with the table view and detail view:

[image: storyBoard]

The tableview works fine the cell are been populated and everything but when one of the cells is been selected I get the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<masterViewController: 0x15ce0e9b0>) has no segue with identifier 'detailView''
```

Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailView" sender:[_arrayOfFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

Here is the info of the detailView:

[image]

I add identifier to the storyboard segue:

[image]

but now I'm getting the following error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'show tableVIew'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the identifier for the segue, not the viewController.  If you click on the line joining the two viewControllers, you can then set the attributes for the segue in the attributes inspector:

[image]

Comment: I did what you suggested but I'm getting this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'show tableVIew'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController. I update my post above

Comment: See @carlodurso's answer below - if you want to use a push segue, you need to wrap your detail view controller in a navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong you should be adding a Navigation Controller to bot the `Master` and `Detail View Controllers`.

[image: screenshot]

Additionally, for a split controller to function it must be set as the root controller.

Good luck!

Comment: but if you add a split view only adds one navigation controller. How Can I add the split view controller with 2 navigation controller?

Comment: Select the View Controller, from the top menu `Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller`.